# How do I pass a hidden input value to plugin onSaveUser event handler?

Tags: plugin-development, user-profile, registration

I'm writing a customer portal plugin, utilizing Crafts user registration form: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form

```
{# User registration form: #}
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">

    {# What do I add / change ? #}

    {# ... #}
</form>
```

My plugin has two different types of account profile records, *.._OrganizationProfileRecord* and *.._UserProfileRecord*. What I want to do is send a variable to the onSaveUser event handler in my plugin main class, to tell it what type of user was just saved (*"org"* or *"user"*), and then take appropriate actions, i.e. create either an organization or user profile.

```
class myPortalPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    public function init()
    { 
        craft()->on('users.onSaveUser', function(Event $event)
        {
            $craftUser = $event->params['user'];
            $isNewUser = $event->params['isNewUser'];

            if ($isNewUser)
            {
                // Check if user is an organization or a regular user, and
                // create the appropriate profile record.

                // How do I check?

                // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### Questions:

1. How would I go about passing data/variable from the form to the onSaveUser event handler?
2. Is there a better / more convenient way to do this?

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide in this matter!  *bowing*

/Monkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Though I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but here's what I did:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userType" value="org">
```

was added to the register form, and ...

```
$userType = craft()->request->getPost('userType');

if ($userType == 'org')
{
    // ...
```

was added to the onSaveUser event handler function.